# no windows boot option after installing ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, windows, boot-repair

I have Windows on my machine and then I installed Ubuntu 12.04 using USB. I was not getting the option to boot into Ubuntu, so I ran boot-repair but then now I am not getting option to boot into windows. Below is my paste ubuntu url. What can be the issue ?

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1199492

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You may refer to [**this post**](http://askubuntu.com/a/101693/71205)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

- You originally couldn't see Ubuntu because one Windows program was using FlexNet DRM, Boot-Repair fixed this problem.
- Your problem now is that your /boot is too far from the start of the disk.
- You have separated many folders. If this is not a server, do not separate /tmp nor /usr, nor /var.

Solution:

1. Via [Gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted), delete all Linux partitions: sda2, sda5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13. Do NOT format sda1.
2. Via the `Ubuntu installer`, create a `30GB` (NOT more) [root partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#Required_partitions) (EXT4, mount point: / )at the start of the disk, just after the sda1 partition.
3. Create a [SWAP partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#Required_partitions) (size of your RAM), just after your root partition.
4. Create a [data partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#Optional_partitions) in the remaining space at the end of the disk.
5. Finish the installation.