# When I select Ubunu my computer just restarts

Tags: 12.04, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu on Windows 8 yesterday, but when I select Ubuntu on the OS selection screen the computer just restarts.

Comment: Did you already read [Installing on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/65926)?

Answer (score 0):

Please check RobinJ's post at [I can't get grub menu to show up during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87409/i-cant-get-grub-menu-to-show-up-during-boot)

In order to see what is going on at boot, edit your grub menu by removing "quiet splash". Then you'll be able of seeing the boot messages and identifying the issue(s).