# Pressing shift does not get me into any grub menu

Tags: 14.04, recovery-mode

I need to get into recovery mode but pressing and holding shift does not work during boot, I also tried tapping shift and f8 but nothing happens, any suggestions? My system runs ubuntu 14.04 and here is my grub file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Did you install GRUB? Are you having dual boot system? Kindly provide these details to help you solve the issue? Also provide information about you installation procedure and how many HDD are there in your system?

Comment: Duplicate of [*I cant get grub menu to show up during boot*](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87409/i-cant-get-grub-menu-to-show-up-during-boot).  You need to remove both the **HIDDEN** items in */etc/default/grub* and run `sudo update-grub`.  This happens if you followed upgrade paths to 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

If the keys aren't working, you can actually edit the `grub config` file so that there is a little bit of a timeout for you.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the value of **GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT** to a number in seconds.  For example if you change it from 0 to 10, it will display the Grub menu for 10 seconds before automatically booting the first option.

Once you have made your desired change and saved the file, close it and run the following command to apply the changes:

```
sudo update-grub
```

After that

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Changed it nothing happens still..

Comment: [GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is badly documented](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/978994): _"when this feature is unset (default), the menu will be displayed, and when it is set, the menu will not be displayed."_

Comment: Also note from `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'`: **GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT** This option is unset by default, and is deprecated in favour of the less confusing `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown` or `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden`