# xubuntu freezes every time

Tags: 14.04, kernel, xubuntu, crash

I am asking this as there does not seem a clear way to diagnose the problem. I have searched several sites including this one. 
After a few minutes Xubuntu freezes and I can't use the mouse or keyboard. I need to hard reboot but the cycle starts again. I have a desktop PC running Xubuntu 14.04 LTS on `kernel 3.13.0-48-generic`. It is an older PC.

Comment: See if this helps https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze

Comment: you can find a lot of answers within this forum explaning that is usually video drivers issue I've also been to such a situation and the problem was `nouveau driver` after installing `nvidia` the problem disappeared. Check what video driver you're using is it stock? `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`

Comment: The driver is:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV620 LE [Radeon HD 3450 AGP] [1002:95c6]
 Subsystem: Hightech Information System Ltd. Device [1787:0028]
 Kernel driver in use: radeon

Comment: Would a graphics card driver stop the keyboard from working?

Comment: Check your CPU cooling fan. CPU may stop working due to high temperature.May be you need to apply a new layer of thermal compound for your CPU.

Comment: @JacquesMALAPRADE Did you try booting the system from an older kernel

Comment: @MuditKapil I did. It still seems to freeze on the previous kernel.

Comment: It seems to happen every time I have firefox open and whilst browsing.

Comment: Have any of you tried the HWE kernel? Install it with "sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic". If you use UEFI, you'll also need "sudo apt-get install linux-signed-generic-lts-utopic". This will install Linux 3.16 which is known to solve a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing this issue on Kubuntu 14.04.  It started after the update to kernel 3.13.0-48-generic

<strike>You can restart the system without hard resetting it by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1 (brings you to command prompt)  Login and then type: "sudo shutdown now -r"  this will at least allow you to bring down the system cleanly.</strike>

I am going to boot into an earlier kernel until there is a new kernel.   Here is a link to an article on how to do it:  [Pressing shift does not get me into any grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463676/pressing-shift-does-not-get-me-into-any-grub-menu)    Update:  Issue had nothing to do with the kernel revision

Comment: guys Ubuntu 14.04LTS uses 3.16.0.30 currently and it works fine I guess you better upgrade not downgrade.

Comment: Looks like the issue had nothing to do with the kernel as it happened with the previous one.  My issue was with the Nouveau driver.  Looks like Jacques has a radeon card so my issue must be something different then his.

Comment: @joker I don't think 3.16 has been released for 14.04 yet.  I have performed all the updates as of yesterday and I get 'code' $ uname -a   Linux system 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I'm using standard Ubuntu 14.04LTS and since February it's got 3.16.0.30 kernel by default. You can run **`sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`** it must say already the latest, if so maybe for Kubuntu is lower then. (there's ( ' ) mark before uname also.