# Input Not Supported Xubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: input

Need Help with my Machine Because Every time I turn on my machine I always get this error Input Not Supported and it takes a little bit of time then immediately it will pop directly to user login.. what should i do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When the computer first boots, do you see the BIOS/POST screen ok? Then what happens, and how long is the "input not supported" message displayed? Like 1-3 seconds, or a half-minute plus?

If it's a second or three, maybe Ubuntu/Xubuntu has changed display modes too fast for your monitor to keep up, but it catches up when the login screen shows up. My monitor flips & flickers for about two seconds right before it logins in.

Update: 30 second delay... That is a long time, sounds about as long as the startup messages would take (like the log messages if you boot without the quiet splash options) - As if your splash screen were in an unsupported resolution. What happens if you boot without the quiet splash options? There are other boot options that are often used for troubleshooting or unsupported hardware, like nomodeset might apply here, but then your regular display might be affected, but could be worth a try to check?

Holding <kbd>shift</kbd> while booting used to get you to the grub menu, (if it wasn't already visible) but that may not work anymore, see these Q's for how-to's if you can't get to the grub/boot menu to change boot options:

- [I can't get grub menu to show up during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87409/i-cant-get-grub-menu-to-show-up-during-boot)
- [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

Or it may be the **grub** and splash screen resolutions that are unsupported, in which case you couldn't change the boot options yet. These answers may help with that:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/6040/129271
- https://askubuntu.com/a/362998/129271

Comment: Every time i turn my PC error message shows for about 30sec or more then it boot up...is this something normal? or maybe a remedy for this kind of problem

Comment: That is a long time, sounds about as long as the startup messages would take (the log messages if you boot without the `quiet splash` options) - As if your splash screen were in an unsupported resolution. What happens if you boot without the `quiet splash` options? There are other boot options that are often used for troubleshooting or unsupported hardware, like `nomodeset` might apply here, but then your regular display might be affected, but could be worth a try to check?

Comment: oh well honestly i am not really an advance user so in short i am still grasping knowledge with this OS and other stuff