# grub(violet screen) did'nt apppear

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

previously i had windows 7 and windows xp.I formatted the drive containing windows xp .i installed ubuntu 15.04 through USB and allocated the previously formatted drive to it.ubuntu installed successfully.it prompted to restart.but after restarting the grub was not showing up.the PC booted normally as it booted before installing ubuntu 15.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't get grub menu to show up during boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87409/i-cant-get-grub-menu-to-show-up-during-boot)

Answer (score 1):

Since i cannot comment i will do it like this,

Take a look at this:
[I can't get grub menu to show up during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87409/i-cant-get-grub-menu-to-show-up-during-boot)