# Cannot enter tty, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, tty

I want to use ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop so I use a bootable USB to install the system.

Now I want to install NVIDIA driver... another story, skip it. Anyway I need to use tty to install the driver as I need to shut down X server.

But when I use `ctrl+alt+F1~6` to enter the tty, nothing happens. The situation is, first I login to my user, stay on the desktop. I press `ctrl+alt+f1`, then my mouse disappear, and the GUI directly got frozen (I test it by playing a youtube video and press the keys).

It looks like I stucked at somethere because if I press `ctrl+alt+f7` the GUI goes back to working. The same thing happens if I tried to enter tty at the login page without logging into my account.

Can anyone help? I can update any information about the system if you need. Thank you.

Edit:

I've read this thread [Boot hangs after installing the latest driver from PPA and Ctrl+Alt+F1 keyboard shortcut doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/901483/boot-hangs-after-installing-the-latest-driver-from-ppa-and-ctrlaltf1-keyboard)

Now I finished step 2 and stucked before enter step 3. After selecting the recovery mode, I only have 'loading linux 4.13.0-36 generic' and 'loading initial ramdisk' these two lines appear, no menu like it is supposed to be in step 3

Comment: @karel will have a try now.

Comment: Please comment if it doesn't work so we can try to fix it another way.

Comment: @karel Of course, now I finished step 2 and stucked before enter step 3. After selecting the recovery mode, I only have 'loading linux 4.13.0-36 generic' and 'loading initial ramdisk' these two lines appear, no menu like it is supposed to be in step 3.

Comment: From Ubuntu documentation [LiveCdRecovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) wiki. 1. Boot the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. 2. Press Ctrl-Alt-F3 3. `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` or type your partition instead of sda1  4. If you created a custom partition layout when installing Ubuntu you have to find your root partition using the `fdisk` utility. 5. `sudo chroot /mnt`

Comment: @karel I boot the laptop with my USB and select try ubuntu without installation, now I am at the desktop and still cannot enter tty.