# Ubuntu 20.04 crashes after some time

Tags: 20.04, themes, crash

Suddenly a few days ago I started Ubuntu 20.04, but after a minute it crashed. The only thing I could move was the mouse. The screen keeps the open files, but otherwise it doesn't respond to anything. It works fine in Windows 10, but in Ubuntu it started crashing suddenly a week after I used a new theme on my GUI.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in Windows 10, but in Ubuntu it started crashing suddenly a week after you installed a theme on your GUI. Uninstall the theme on your GUI from text-only recovery mode.

Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GNU GRUB menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

The timing when to press the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key can be tricky, so sometimes if you miss it you need to try it again. If that doesn't work try the answers to [I can't get the GRUB menu to show up during boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/87409/).

You will see a GNU GRUB menu screen that looks like this. Select **Advanced options for Ubuntu** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

A new purple screen will appear showing a list of kernels, which includes options of booting the kernels normally or in recovery mode.

[image]

Press the down arrow key until you select the **2nd entry from the top** (the one with the **recovery mode in the description**) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice.

Now you should see this recovery menu:

[image: recovery menu]

Using the arrow keys scroll down to **network** (the third entry from the bottom in the Recovery Menu) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Using the arrow keys scroll down to **root** (the second entry from the bottom in the Recovery Menu) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should now see a root prompt and you can run commands from it. Uninstall the GUI theme that you installed last week and reboot with `reboot`.

Comment: i can't i try to do it and then it crushes

Comment: @Lance Uninstall the theme on your GUI from text-only recovery mode.