# Pressing login makes the screen black

Tags: boot, grub2, login, login-screen

I am new to Ubuntu and I decided to change to it from windows due to my work.I successfully installed it but after I press login my screen gets blank and flashing some part of my screen as on screenshot:[failed to boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvRoN.jpg)

When I press esc at the first boot I can successfully login and use it.Is there at least any way to display grub everytime I start my pc?(also while using if it goes to sleep mode it does the same thing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't get grub menu to show up during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87409/i-cant-get-grub-menu-to-show-up-during-boot)